# Exception when parsing Json response from Swift api

Tags: jclouds, openstack-swift

I have some files uploaded in openstacks' object store. This snippet fetches container and object list and prints.

```
private void listContainers() {
      ContainerApi containerApi = swiftApi.getContainerApiForRegion("region");
      Set<Container> containers = containerApi.list().toSet();

      for (Container container : containers) {
          ObjectApi objectApi = swiftApi.getObjectApiForRegionAndContainer("region", container.getName());

          ObjectList objects = objectApi.list();  // crashes here
          for (SwiftObject object: objects) {
             System.out.println("\t\t"+ object);
          }

          System.out.println("\t" + container);
      }
   }
```

console output:

```
DEBUG o.j.rest.internal.InvokeHttpMethod - >> invoking container:list
DEBUG o.j.h.i.JavaUrlHttpCommandExecutorService - Sending request -363056976: GET http://127.0.0.1/swift/v1/?format=json HTTP/1.1
DEBUG jclouds.headers - >> GET http://127.0.0.1/swift/v1/?format=json HTTP/1.1
DEBUG jclouds.headers - >> Accept: application/json
DEBUG jclouds.headers - >> X-Auth-Token: MIIQ...
DEBUG o.j.h.i.JavaUrlHttpCommandExecutorService - Receiving response -363056976: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
DEBUG jclouds.headers - << HTTP/1.1 200 OK
DEBUG jclouds.headers - << Transfer-Encoding: chunked
DEBUG jclouds.headers - << Date: Tue, 25 Nov 2014 07:39:44 GMT
DEBUG jclouds.headers - << Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=98
DEBUG jclouds.headers - << Connection: Keep-Alive
DEBUG jclouds.headers - << Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
DEBUG jclouds.headers - << Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
DEBUG jclouds.wire - << "[{"name":"jclouds-example","count":1,"bytes":12},{"name":"test_name","count":3,"bytes":22008217}]"
DEBUG o.j.rest.internal.InvokeHttpMethod - >> invoking object:list
DEBUG o.j.h.i.JavaUrlHttpCommandExecutorService - Sending request -1472717862: GET http://127.0.0.1/swift/v1/jclouds-example/?format=json HTTP/1.1
DEBUG jclouds.headers - >> GET http://127.0.0.1/swift/v1/jclouds-example/?format=json HTTP/1.1
DEBUG jclouds.headers - >> Accept: application/json
DEBUG jclouds.headers - >> X-Auth-Token: MIIQ...
DEBUG o.j.h.i.JavaUrlHttpCommandExecutorService - Receiving response -1472717862: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
DEBUG jclouds.headers - << HTTP/1.1 200 OK
DEBUG jclouds.headers - << Transfer-Encoding: chunked
DEBUG jclouds.headers - << Date: Tue, 25 Nov 2014 07:39:44 GMT
DEBUG jclouds.headers - << Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=97
DEBUG jclouds.headers - << Connection: Keep-Alive
DEBUG jclouds.headers - << Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
DEBUG jclouds.headers - << Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
DEBUG jclouds.wire - << "[{"name":"jclouds-example.txt","hash":"ed076287532e86365e841e92bfc50d8c","bytes":12,"content_type":"application\/unknown","last_modified":"2014-11-25T07:39:44.000Z"}]"
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:404)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:483)
    at org.jclouds.openstack.swift.v1.functions.ParseContainerFromHeaders.apply(ParseContainerFromHeaders.java:39)
    at org.jclouds.openstack.swift.v1.functions.ParseObjectListFromResponse.apply(ParseObjectListFromResponse.java:66)
    at org.jclouds.openstack.swift.v1.functions.ParseObjectListFromResponse.apply(ParseObjectListFromResponse.java:41)
    at org.jclouds.rest.internal.InvokeHttpMethod.invoke(InvokeHttpMethod.java:90)
    at org.jclouds.rest.internal.InvokeHttpMethod.apply(InvokeHttpMethod.java:73)
    at org.jclouds.rest.internal.InvokeHttpMethod.apply(InvokeHttpMethod.java:44)
    at org.jclouds.reflect.FunctionalReflection$FunctionalInvocationHandler.handleInvocation(FunctionalReflection.java:117)
    at com.google.common.reflect.AbstractInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractInvocationHandler.java:87)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy66.list(Unknown Source)
    at test.jcloud.JCloudsSwift.listContainers(JCloudsSwift.java:99)
    at test.jcloud.JCloudsSwift.main(JCloudsSwift.java:39)
```

If I specify file name and fetch its' metadata, everything works fine:

```
...
for (Container container : containers) {
    ObjectApi objectApi = swiftApi.getObjectApiForRegionAndContainer("region", container.getName());
    SwiftObject obj = objectApi.get("jclouds-example.txt");
    System.out.println("--  "+obj.getMetadata());
    ObjectList objects = objectApi.list();
...
```

console output:

```
DEBUG o.j.rest.internal.InvokeHttpMethod - >> invoking object:get
DEBUG o.j.h.i.JavaUrlHttpCommandExecutorService - Sending request -614124758: GET http://127.0.0.1/swift/v1/jclouds-example/jclouds-example.txt HTTP/1.1
DEBUG jclouds.headers - >> GET http://127.0.0.1/swift/v1/jclouds-example/jclouds-example.txt HTTP/1.1
DEBUG jclouds.headers - >> Accept: application/json
DEBUG jclouds.headers - >> X-Auth-Token: MIIQ...
DEBUG o.j.h.i.JavaUrlHttpCommandExecutorService - Receiving response -614124758: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
DEBUG jclouds.headers - << HTTP/1.1 200 OK
DEBUG jclouds.headers - << etag: ed076287532e86365e841e92bfc50d8c
DEBUG jclouds.headers - << Date: Tue, 25 Nov 2014 07:48:49 GMT
DEBUG jclouds.headers - << Last-Modified: Tue, 25 Nov 2014 07:48:49 GMT
DEBUG jclouds.headers - << Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=97
DEBUG jclouds.headers - << X-Object-Meta-key4: blu
DEBUG jclouds.headers - << X-Object-Meta-key3: value3
DEBUG jclouds.headers - << Connection: Keep-Alive
DEBUG jclouds.headers - << Accept-Ranges: bytes
DEBUG jclouds.headers - << Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
DEBUG jclouds.headers - << Content-Type: application/unknown
DEBUG jclouds.headers - << Content-Length: 12
DEBUG jclouds.wire - << "Hello World!"
--  {key4=blu, key3=value3}
```

The code is based on [this](https://jclouds.apache.org/guides/openstack/#swift) example and getting object info on [this](https://github.com/jclouds/jclouds-examples/blob/master/rackspace/src/main/java/org/jclouds/examples/rackspace/cloudfiles/ListObjects.java#L77) example

**Problem**

I get `NumberFormatException` when jclouds converts json data containing object list to java object.

**Question**

How can I get the file list for each container and get their metadata?

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this on OpenStack Juno with jclouds 1.8.1 and it's working for me. What versions of OpenStack and jclouds are you using?

I also noticed the object list response is missing the `X-Container-Object-Count` and `X-Container-Bytes-Used` headers. That's odd, they should be there according to this [api reference](http://developer.openstack.org/api-ref-objectstorage-v1.html#storage_container_services). Is your Apache server maybe manipulating or filtering headers?

If you want to try jclouds 1.8.1, you'll want to read these [release notes](http://jclouds.apache.org/releasenotes/1.8.1/) first.

Comment: I'm using jclouds 1.8.1 and openstack 2014.1

Comment: Swift really should be retuning the X-Container-Object-Count and X-Container-Bytes-Used headers, they've been around since long before 2014.1 (see [server.py](https://github.com/openstack/swift/blob/fbc58b082cf93eb142c038f24e75ec01e6005894/swift/container/server.py#L62-70)). Is your Apache server maybe manipulating or filtering headers?

Comment: Also, how did you get the request to end with ?format=json `GET http://127.0.0.1/swift/v1/jclouds-example/?format=json`? There's no way to do that when calling ObjectApi.list() in 1.8.1 (see [ObjectApi.java](https://github.com/jclouds/jclouds/blob/master/apis/openstack-swift/src/main/java/org/jclouds/openstack/swift/v1/features/ObjectApi.java#L79-84)).

Comment: I downloaded the source of jclouds 1.8.1 and it differs from the github copy. For example `ObjectApi` method `ObjectList list();` has tag __@QueryParams(keys = "format", values = "json")__

Comment: Can you please send a link to *exactly* what you downloaded?

Comment: I use maven example from jclouds [website](https://jclouds.apache.org/start/install/). The sources were downloaded via maven

Comment: If that's the case, the canonical sources are coming from [sources.jar](https://repository.apache.org/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?r=releases&g=org.apache.jclouds.api&a=openstack-swift&v=1.8.1&e=jar&c=sources) on repository.apache.org (also in [sources.jar](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/jclouds/api/openstack-swift/1.8.1/openstack-swift-1.8.1-sources.jar) on Maven Central). Both agree with GitHub [ObjectApi.java](https://github.com/jclouds/jclouds/blob/jclouds-1.8.1/apis/openstack-swift/src/main/java/org/jclouds/openstack/swift/v1/features/ObjectApi.java).

Comment: I'd love to know about that discrepancy too, as I think that's relevant for an issue I'm having where JClouds will not add that param to the querystring and therefore Swift will return the answer in plain/text format, so I'll get an error : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35439056/jclouds-and-openstack-illegalstateexception-expected-begin-array-but-was-stri