# JClouds and OpenStack : IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING

Tags: java, openstack, jclouds, ceph

I'm trying to access [OpenStack Swift](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/) using [Apache JClouds](http://jclouds.apache.org/) 1.9.2 library. Maven dependency :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.jclouds</groupId>
    <artifactId>jclouds-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I began with the [getting started guide](https://jclouds.apache.org/guides/openstack/#swift) and its code sample. In general, I have no problem to connect and persist a blob. But when I try to list the list of containers (or the contents of a container) I get the following error :

```
SEVERE: Error parsing input: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:817)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:770)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:719)
    at org.jclouds.json.internal.GsonWrapper.fromJson(GsonWrapper.java:42)
    at org.jclouds.http.functions.ParseJson.apply(ParseJson.java:83)
    at org.jclouds.http.functions.ParseJson.apply(ParseJson.java:77)
    at org.jclouds.http.functions.ParseJson.apply(ParseJson.java:62)
    at org.jclouds.http.functions.ParseJson.apply(ParseJson.java:42)
    at org.jclouds.rest.internal.InvokeHttpMethod.invoke(InvokeHttpMethod.java:90)
    at org.jclouds.rest.internal.InvokeHttpMethod.apply(InvokeHttpMethod.java:73)
    at org.jclouds.rest.internal.InvokeHttpMethod.apply(InvokeHttpMethod.java:44)
    at org.jclouds.reflect.FunctionalReflection$FunctionalInvocationHandler.handleInvocation(FunctionalReflection.java:117)
    at com.google.common.reflect.AbstractInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractInvocationHandler.java:87)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy57.list(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginArray(JsonReader.java:351)
    at org.jclouds.json.internal.NullFilteringTypeAdapterFactories$IterableTypeAdapter.readAndBuild(NullFilteringTypeAdapterFactories.java:88)
    at org.jclouds.json.internal.NullFilteringTypeAdapterFactories$IterableTypeAdapter.read(NullFilteringTypeAdapterFactories.java:82)
    at org.jclouds.json.internal.NullFilteringTypeAdapterFactories$FluentIterableTypeAdapter.read(NullFilteringTypeAdapterFactories.java:239)
    at org.jclouds.json.internal.NullFilteringTypeAdapterFactories$FluentIterableTypeAdapter.read(NullFilteringTypeAdapterFactories.java:225)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:805)
```

The code below taken from the sample that will fail when executing `containerApi.list()` . As commented, methods `createContainer` and `uploadObjectFromString` will work.

I can only think that Swift is returning a response in a JSON format slightly different from what JClouds is expecting but I don't know whether this is true or how to solve it. 
Also, I see in my OpenStack Dashboard that although 
Object Store is http://xx.xx.xx.107:80/swift/v1
Identity is http://xx.xx.xx.101:5000/v2.0
Not sure why one of them would be v1 and the other v2.0 and whether I should take this into account when using the Java libraries. 
I don't think I have a restriction about what Java libraries to use, so I wonder whether I'd better use another one instead of JClouds, although this one looked like the most suitable one.

```
import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Set;
import org.jclouds.ContextBuilder;
import org.jclouds.openstack.swift.v1.SwiftApi;
import org.jclouds.openstack.swift.v1.domain.Container;
import org.jclouds.openstack.swift.v1.features.ContainerApi;
import com.google.common.io.Closeables;
public class JCloudsSwift implements Closeable {
    private SwiftApi swiftApi;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JCloudsSwift jcloudsSwift = new JCloudsSwift();

          try {
             jcloudsSwift.listContainers();
             jcloudsSwift.close();
          } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          } finally {
             try {
                jcloudsSwift.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
          }
    }
    public JCloudsSwift() {
          String provider = "openstack-swift";
          String identity = "tenantName:userName";
          String credential = "password";
          String endPoint = "http://xx.xx.xx.101:5000/v2.0/";
          swiftApi = ContextBuilder.newBuilder(provider)
                .endpoint(endPoint)
                .credentials(identity, credential)
                .buildApi(SwiftApi.class);
       }
       private void listContainers() {
          String region = "us-east-1a";
          ContainerApi containerApi = swiftApi.getContainerApi(region);
          Set<Container> containers = containerApi.list().toSet();
          for (Container container : containers) {
             System.out.println("  " + container);
          }
       }
       public void close() throws IOException {
          Closeables.close(swiftApi, true);
       }
}
```

Following zachsh's suggestion, I enabled the *wire log* (see below). I hid some details (IPs...). Hopefully I didn't compromise anything there.

It looks to me that at first, there is a call to the identity v2 endpoint which gets a **valid JSON response providing the different endpoints**, like the one with swift v1. Both content-type in the request and the response are `application/json`. Then, this swift endpoint is called but it will only return the **response in plain text**. That is, the request content-type in the request is `application/json` and in the response it´s `text/plain` . "Dev" and "dev2" are the names of my two containers in the object store.

I wonder whether there is anything wrong in my Java code (I mostly copied the example but I may have misconfigured something), or something about the libraries I use, or even something in my Openstack installation (I have no control over it, but I could ask for specifics).

See logs below.

**jclouds-wire.log**

```
2016-02-17 09:31:04,562 DEBUG [jclouds.wire] [main] >> "Sensitive data in payload, use PROPERTY_LOGGER_WIRE_LOG_SENSITIVE_INFO override to enable logging this data."
2016-02-17 09:31:04,562 DEBUG [jclouds.headers] [main] >> POST http://xx.xx.xx.101:5000/v2.0/tokens HTTP/1.1
2016-02-17 09:31:04,562 DEBUG [jclouds.headers] [main] >> Accept: application/json
2016-02-17 09:31:04,562 DEBUG [jclouds.headers] [main] >> Content-Type: application/json
2016-02-17 09:31:04,562 DEBUG [jclouds.headers] [main] >> Content-Length: 103
2016-02-17 09:31:04,984 DEBUG [jclouds.headers] [main] << HTTP/1.1 200 OK
2016-02-17 09:31:04,984 DEBUG [jclouds.headers] [main] << X-Distribution: Ubuntu
2016-02-17 09:31:04,984 DEBUG [jclouds.headers] [main] << Connection: keep-alive
2016-02-17 09:31:04,984 DEBUG [jclouds.headers] [main] << Vary: X-Auth-Token
2016-02-17 09:31:04,984 DEBUG [jclouds.headers] [main] << Date: Wed, 17 Feb 2016 09:31:27 GMT
2016-02-17 09:31:04,984 DEBUG [jclouds.headers] [main] << Content-Type: application/json
2016-02-17 09:31:04,984 DEBUG [jclouds.headers] [main] << Content-Length: 4421
2016-02-17 09:31:04,999 DEBUG [jclouds.wire] [main] << "{"access": {"token": {"issued_at": "2016-02-17T09:31:27.785179", "expires": "2016-02-17T10:31:27Z", "id": "fb6b46bd674046ef87c3270f1fd9dafd", "tenant": {"description": "", "enabled": true, "id": "c2c919f7f89a4d8f913e4ce19a0e6ace", "name": "my_tenant_name"}, "audit_ids": ["nIjY-heVSV-cbTfVIpEY-Q"]}, "serviceCatalog": [{"endpoints": [{"adminURL": "http://xx.xx.xx.102:8774/v2/c2c919f7f89a4d8f913e4ce19a0e6ace", "region": "us-east-1a", "internalURL": "http://xx.xx.xx.102:8774/v2/c2c919f7f89a4d8f913e4ce19a0e6ace", "id": "70c3eef4d3e242348c0e580f94414823", "publicURL": "http://xx.xx.xx.102:8774/v2/c2c919f7f89a4d8f913e4ce19a0e6ace"}], "endpoints_links": [], "type": "compute", "name": "nova"}, {"endpoints": [{"adminURL": "http://xx.xx.xx.105:9696", "region": "us-east-1a", "internalURL": "http://xx.xx.xx.105:9696", "id": "2a9328b17cc54538a38fb6ae13e5b3ac", "publicURL": "http://xx.xx.xx.105:9696"}], "endpoints_links": [], "type": "network", "name": "quantum"}, {"endpoints": [{"adminURL": "http://xx.xx.xx.104:8776/v2/c2c919f7f89a4d8f913e4ce19a0e6ace", "region": "us-east-1a", "internalURL": "http://xx.xx.xx.104:8776/v2/c2c919f7f89a4d8f913e4ce19a0e6ace", "id": "2eda4420ba0a49f9891ed9bd803b569c", "publicURL": "http://xx.xx.xx.104:8776/v2/c2c919f7f89a4d8f913e4ce19a0e6ace"}], "endpoints_links": [], "type": "volumev2", "name": "cinderv2"}, {"endpoints": [{"adminURL": "http://xx.xx.xx.102:3333", "region": "us-east-1a", "internalURL": "http://xx.xx.xx.102:3333", "id": "538aab805479410da21399abd012ceff", "publicURL": "http://xx.xx.xx.102:3333"}], "endpoints_links": [], "type": "s3", "name": "s3"}, {"endpoints": [{"adminURL": "http://xx.xx.xx.103:9292", "region": "us-east-1a", "internalURL": "http://xx.xx.xx.103:9292", "id": "80559923bf354541bdd9f56a45bedd7a", "publicURL": "http://xx.xx.xx.103:9292"}], "endpoints_links": [], "type": "image", "name": "glance"}, {"endpoints": [{"adminURL": "http://xx.xx.xx.108:8777", "region": "us-east-1a", "internalURL": "http://xx.xx.xx.108:8777", "id": "a777efdc724643ecb6e705ff2eb47004", "publicURL": "http://xx.xx.xx.108:8777"}], "endpoints_links": [], "type": "metering", "name": "ceilometer"}, {"endpoints": [{"adminURL": "http://xx.xx.xx.220:8000/v1", "region": "us-east-1a", "internalURL": "http://xx.xx.xx.220:8000/v1", "id": "253135e684c24e00bb7bea6feb7cf595", "publicURL": "http://xx.xx.xx.220:8000/v1"}], "endpoints_links": [], "type": "cloudformation", "name": "heat-cfn"}, {"endpoints": [{"adminURL": "http://xx.xx.xx.104:8776/v1/c2c919f7f89a4d8f913e4ce19a0e6ace", "region": "us-east-1a", "internalURL": "http://xx.xx.xx.104:8776/v1/c2c919f7f89a4d8f913e4ce19a0e6ace", "id": "38264ccfbb574fcd81ba345c9eb7d37b", "publicURL": "http://xx.xx.xx.104:8776/v1/c2c919f7f89a4d8f913e4ce19a0e6ace"}], "endpoints_links": [], "type": "volume", "name": "cinder"}, {"endpoints": [{"adminURL": "http://xx.xx.xx.102:8773/services/Cloud", "region": "us-east-1a", "internalURL": "http://xx.xx.xx.102:8773/services/Cloud", "id": "4da43f1139c94d8aaf82564e16156ca5", "publicURL": "http://xx.xx.xx.102:8773/services/Cloud"}], "endpoints_links": [], "type": "ec2", "name": "ec2"}, {"endpoints": [{"adminURL": "http://xx.xx.xx.220:8004/v1/c2c919f7f89a4d8f913e4ce19a0e6ace", "region": "us-east-1a", "internalURL": "http://xx.xx.xx.220:8004/v1/c2c919f7f89a4d8f913e4ce19a0e6ace", "id": "1180dc51deea4523a088871a352d9f72", "publicURL": "http://xx.xx.xx.220:8004/v1/c2c919f7f89a4d8f913e4ce19a0e6ace"}], "endpoints_links": [], "type": "orchestration", "name": "heat"}, {"endpoints": [{"adminURL": "http://xx.xx.xx.107:80/swift", "region": "us-east-1a", "internalURL": "http://xx.xx.xx.107:80/swift/v1", "id": "0457cd31064243c9b548dfe2eb0c1bc8", "publicURL": "http://xx.xx.xx.107:80/swift/v1"}], "endpoints_links": [], "type": "object-store", "name": "swift"}, {"endpoints": [{"adminURL": "http://xx.xx.xx.101:35357/v2.0", "region": "us-east-1a", "internalURL": "http://xx.xx.xx.101:5000/v2.0", "id": "40d04c8899cc4ea083dc5ecac808a825", "publicURL": "http://xx.xx.xx.101:5000/v2.0"}], "endpoints_links": [], "type": "identity", "name": "keystone"}], "user": {"username": "my_user_name", "roles_links": [], "id": "e9312e8a3579404d91ba53894dcf72ea", "roles": [{"name": "Member"}, {"name": "_member_"}], "name": "my_user_name"}, "metadata": {"is_admin": 0, "roles": ["647df06e706f4d1f8a8810246e19bd26", "9fe2ff9ee4384b1894a90878d3e92bab"]}}}"
2016-02-17 09:31:05,062 DEBUG [jclouds.headers] [main] >> GET http://xx.xx.xx.107:80/swift/v1 HTTP/1.1
2016-02-17 09:31:05,062 DEBUG [jclouds.headers] [main] >> Accept: application/json
2016-02-17 09:31:05,062 DEBUG [jclouds.headers] [main] >> X-Auth-Token: fb6b46bd674046ef87c3270f1fd9dafd
2016-02-17 09:31:05,405 DEBUG [jclouds.headers] [main] << HTTP/1.1 200 OK
2016-02-17 09:31:05,405 DEBUG [jclouds.headers] [main] << Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
2016-02-17 09:31:05,405 DEBUG [jclouds.headers] [main] << Connection: Keep-Alive
2016-02-17 09:31:05,405 DEBUG [jclouds.headers] [main] << Date: Wed, 17 Feb 2016 09:31:28 GMT
2016-02-17 09:31:05,405 DEBUG [jclouds.headers] [main] << Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
2016-02-17 09:31:05,405 DEBUG [jclouds.headers] [main] << Content-Length: 9
2016-02-17 09:31:05,405 DEBUG [jclouds.wire] [main] << "dev[\n]"
2016-02-17 09:31:05,405 DEBUG [jclouds.wire] [main] << "dev2[\n]"
```

**jclouds.log**

```
2016-02-17 09:31:04,562 DEBUG [org.jclouds.rest.internal.InvokeHttpMethod] [main] >> invoking AuthenticationApi.authenticateWithTenantNameAndCredentials
2016-02-17 09:31:04,562 DEBUG [org.jclouds.http.internal.JavaUrlHttpCommandExecutorService] [main] Sending request -1271935931: POST http://xx.xx.xx.101:5000/v2.0/tokens HTTP/1.1
2016-02-17 09:31:04,984 DEBUG [org.jclouds.http.internal.JavaUrlHttpCommandExecutorService] [main] Receiving response -1271935931: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
2016-02-17 09:31:05,046 DEBUG [org.jclouds.openstack.keystone.v2_0.suppliers.RegionIdToURIFromAccessForTypeAndVersion] [main] endpoints for apiType object-store and version 1: {us-east-1a=[Endpoint{id=0457cd31064243c9b548dfe2eb0c1bc8, region=us-east-1a, publicURL=http://xx.xx.xx.107:80/swift/v1, internalURL=http://xx.xx.xx.107:80/swift/v1, adminURL=http://xx.xx.xx.107:80/swift}]}
2016-02-17 09:31:05,062 DEBUG [org.jclouds.rest.internal.InvokeHttpMethod] [main] >> invoking container:list
2016-02-17 09:31:05,062 DEBUG [org.jclouds.http.internal.JavaUrlHttpCommandExecutorService] [main] Sending request -629919459: GET http://xx.xx.xx.107:80/swift/v1 HTTP/1.1
2016-02-17 09:31:05,405 DEBUG [org.jclouds.http.internal.JavaUrlHttpCommandExecutorService] [main] Receiving response -629919459: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
2016-02-17 09:31:05,420 ERROR [org.jclouds.http.functions.ParseJson] [main] Error parsing input: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:817)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:770)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:719)
    at org.jclouds.json.internal.GsonWrapper.fromJson(GsonWrapper.java:42)
    at org.jclouds.http.functions.ParseJson.apply(ParseJson.java:83)
    at org.jclouds.http.functions.ParseJson.apply(ParseJson.java:77)
    at org.jclouds.http.functions.ParseJson.apply(ParseJson.java:62)
    at org.jclouds.http.functions.ParseJson.apply(ParseJson.java:42)
    at org.jclouds.rest.internal.InvokeHttpMethod.invoke(InvokeHttpMethod.java:90)
    at org.jclouds.rest.internal.InvokeHttpMethod.apply(InvokeHttpMethod.java:73)
    at org.jclouds.rest.internal.InvokeHttpMethod.apply(InvokeHttpMethod.java:44)
    at org.jclouds.reflect.FunctionalReflection$FunctionalInvocationHandler.handleInvocation(FunctionalReflection.java:117)
    at com.google.common.reflect.AbstractInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractInvocationHandler.java:87)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy57.list(Unknown Source)
    at com.ceph.JCloudsSwift.listContainers(JCloudsSwift.java:58)
    at com.ceph.JCloudsSwift.main(JCloudsSwift.java:22)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginArray(JsonReader.java:351)
    at org.jclouds.json.internal.NullFilteringTypeAdapterFactories$IterableTypeAdapter.readAndBuild(NullFilteringTypeAdapterFactories.java:88)
    at org.jclouds.json.internal.NullFilteringTypeAdapterFactories$IterableTypeAdapter.read(NullFilteringTypeAdapterFactories.java:82)
    at org.jclouds.json.internal.NullFilteringTypeAdapterFactories$FluentIterableTypeAdapter.read(NullFilteringTypeAdapterFactories.java:239)
    at org.jclouds.json.internal.NullFilteringTypeAdapterFactories$FluentIterableTypeAdapter.read(NullFilteringTypeAdapterFactories.java:225)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:805)
    ... 15 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Do you have a wire log? https://jclouds.apache.org/reference/logging/

Comment: @zacksh Thanks for your comment. I was actually wondering how to debug what was happening underneath. I will update the post accordingly and add the logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a bug. Thanks! Will track here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCLOUDS-1080

Comment: FYI, I can see how adding `@QueryParams(keys = "format", values = "json")` for any @GET method in the `ContainerApi.java` , `ObjectApi.java` etc would solve this issue. Then some other will show up. For example, I'm getting some empty fields so that in `ParseContainerFromHeaders` and `ParseObjectListFromResponse` would get errors when mapping null to long and similar. Some null checks are needed. Not sure whether you want to take this offline, as I think it would be good to apply a couple of fixes.

Comment: Interesting, do you want to send an email to the user mailing list? I think you already did that?

Comment: Yes, that was me, taking it offline. Sorry if that pull request was a bit messy, I'm just starting with Github. I'll try to document it better.

Comment: As an update for whoever finds the same issue, I created a pull request to fix this which has already been merged into master : https://github.com/jclouds/jclouds/pull/923 That should be available for upcoming 2.0.0 release. Thanks everybody from JClouds project.